# Why symbols are unavailable in later dlopened .so file?

Tags: android, android-ndk, dlopen

I am trying to build a walkaround for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73343934/how-to-get-the-library-namespace-in-android-dlextinfo-for-android-dlopen-ext) question. The method is to move all code about Python into a separate so file and make a loader to load and run it. In my opinion, the `dlopen` should load all symbols into a default namespace, then I can bypass the namespace issue.

Here is the loader in JNI:

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_app_NativeLoader_load(
    JNIEnv* env,
    jobject /* this */,
    jstring jLibraryPath) {
    const char *libraryPath = env->GetStringUTFChars(jLibraryPath, NULL);

    void *handle = dlopen(libraryPath, RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (handle == nullptr) {
        LOGD("load %s failed: %s", libraryPath, dlerror());
        goto exit;
    }

    // The lib is loaded successfully
    // Then I should load the entry function, and run it.
    // But here is another test:
    void *sym = dlsym(handle, "PyExc_SystemError"); ///< this works

    void *handle_2 = dlopen("/some/path/to/_csv.cpython-310.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (handle_2 == nullptr) {
        // !!! It goes here, but it shouldn't.
        LOGD("load _csv.cpython-310.so failed: %s", dlerror());
    }

exit:
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jLibraryPath, libraryPath);
}
```

It confirmed that, the `PyExc_SystemError` is in the main library, but when I `dlopen` the `_csv.cpython-310.so`, it said:

```
 03:57:17.744  3102  3102 D example: load /data/app/com.example.app-v4JTCukKIPJdXmBSnDMO6A==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64/_csv.cpython-310.so failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "PyExc_SystemError" referenced by "/data/app/com.example.app-v4JTCukKIPJdXmBSnDMO6A==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64/_csv.cpython-310.so"
```

The runtime environment is Android 9.0/10.0/11.0, and NDK r25. Why the symbols are unavailable?

Comment: Which `LOGD` produced the quoted error message? I'd think it was the first one, as the second one has different string-literal.

Comment: No, it's the second. The first `dlopen` load success.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why it happens like that.

When you show the dlerror, it tells that `PyExc_SystemError` wasn't found, so I think it's the error message from the dlsym, not from the second dlopen.

Your dlsym did not work properly on my opinion, and you should have tested the good loading like that :

```
 
    // load the symbol
    typedef void (*func_loaded_type();

    // reset errors
    dlerror();
    func_loaded_type func_loaded = (func_loaded_type) dlsym(handle, "PyExc_SystemError");
    const char *dlsym_error = dlerror();
    if (dlsym_error) {
        cerr << "Cannot load symbol 'hello': " << dlsym_error <<
            '\n';
        dlclose(handle);
        return 1;
    }
```

If I'm right, it should enter the if bracket. And the reason why it failed to load might be because you did not use `extern "C"` when writing and compiling the .so file that you load in the first place.

But your other problem is that "handle_2 == nullptr" is true and it should not. As I suppose before, the dlerror displayed is from the dlsym, and this might be caused by the fact you did not reset the dlerror. To do that, just place `dlerror();` before the line of your second dlopen().

For more info, or if I'm wrong, go check this [good tutorial on dlopen](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/intro.html). It might lighten you.